# How to display in a nice and safe way an XML string using angular

Tags: xml, angular, xml-parsing

I am using angular 5 and I'm stuck on my problem for a while, and couldn't find an answer.
In short, My program is getting some XML's from a service as a string (when each query is a key in a map) and than suppose to display it, the XML itself is a bit long and not always is formatted correctly. 
I tried to use `xml-beatifier` but it keeps throwing errors which I believe as to do with the XML format.
Any help would be very appreciated!

---

**FYI**
My program manages to display the XML but as a long (ugly) string.
**FYI 2**
I'm very new in Angular and have a very basic knowledge in Web application

---

**my .ts code:**

```
...
import beautify from 'xml-beautifier';

@Component({
    selector: 'obj-fetch',
    templateUrl: './obj-fetch.html',
    styleUrls: ['../base-components/obj-fetch.css'],
    providers: [ElkService],
})

export class ObjFetch extends ObjFetchBase {


    @Input("raj")
    public chosenRaj: string;
    logLines: any;
    objEntries: string[];

    constructor(private elkService: ElkService) {
        super();
        this.name = "Request-Response";
    }

    fetch() {
        this.index = -1;
        this.fetchDisabled = true;
        this.logLines = null;
        this.objEntries = [];
        this.panelMessage = '';
        if (this.chosenobjs) {
            this.elkService.getRequestResponse(this.chosenObjs, this.chosenTemplate, this.chosenEnv, this.chosenDate, this.chosenRaj).subscribe(
                (requestResponse: Map<string,string>) => {
                    this.objEntries = Object.keys(requestResponse);
            if (requestResponse === null || this.objEntries.length === 0) {
                this.panelMessage = "no logs per the above data";
            } else {
                for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(requestResponse)) { 
                    console.log("one")
                    requestResponse[key] = beautify(value+''); //Keep throwing error. 
                }
                this.logLines = requestResponse;
                this.fetchDisabled = false;
                this.index = 0;
            }
        } , (error: any) => {
            this.panelMessage = error.message;
        });
       } else {
        this.panelMessage = "Obj must be specified to in order to get logs";
        }
    }
}
```

**My .html file:**

```
<p-accordion [activeIndex]="index">
    <p-accordionTab [disabled]="fetchDisabled">
        <p-header>
            <span class="acc-query-name">{{name}}</span>
            <button pButton type="button" class="accordionButton ui-button-info" (click)="fetch()" label="Run" ></button>
            <span class="acc-query-header-details">{{panelMessage}}</span>
        </p-header>
        <div *ngIf="logLines && logLines.length != []">
            <p-fieldset *ngFor="let objEntry of objEntries" [toggleable]="true">
                <p-header class="fieldSetHeader">{{objEntry}}</p-header>
                <div *ngFor="let line of logLines[objEntry]">
                    {{line}}
                </div>
            </p-fieldset>
        </div>
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

Comment: you can use https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/ supports most of the languages

Comment: for angular "ngx-monaco-editor": "^6.0.0"

Comment: Cool, thanks I will read about it(: